# Jetpack Compose WebView Handling Back Navigation And Go To Previous Page

Tags: android, kotlin, android-webview, android-jetpack-compose, onbackpressed

I am using Jetpack Compose and have a `WebView` wrapped in a `AndroidView` composable that looks like the following:

```
AndroidView(modifier = modifier, factory = { context ->
        WebView(context).apply {
            layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
            )
            webViewClient = WebViewClient()
            settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        }
    }, update = { webView -> webView.loadUrl(url) })
```

In the legacy way, we could add a `OnBackPressedDispatcher` to the `Activity` to intercept the back press and navigate inside the `WebView` by accessing it via viewBinding for example with functions of the `WebView` like `goBack()` and to check if you can go back with `canGoBack()`.

But how can we achieve the same with this Jetpack Compose approach?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with assigning the WebView to an external var so that's what I've done here.

```
var backEnabled by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
var webView: WebView? = null
AndroidView(
    modifier = modifier,
    factory = { context ->
        WebView(context).apply {
            layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
            )
            webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
                override fun onPageStarted(view: WebView, url: String?, favicon: Bitmap?) {
                    backEnabled = view.canGoBack()
                }
            }
            settings.javaScriptEnabled = true

            loadUrl(url)
            webView = this
        }
    }, update = {
        webView = it
    })

BackHandler(enabled = backEnabled) {
    webView?.goBack()
}
```

The `WebViewClient` listens for `onPageStarted` which checks if the WebView can navigate backwards and then updates `backEnabled`. This causes a recomposition which toggles the [BackHandler](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/activity/compose/package-summary#backhandler) on and off.

I've also moved `loadUrl` out of the `update` function and into `factory` because update is called every time there's a recomposition whereas factory is only called the once.  This may or may not be relevant based on your implementation.

Comment: You should `remember` even the webView.

Comment: What about back button in topbar?

Comment: @SadeghJ You can manage this with "if else", call your own navigation in the click of topbar: IconButton(onClick = {
                        if (backEnabled) {
                            webView?.goBack()
                        } else {
                            popBackStack()
                        }
                    })

Answer (score 1):

You can also take a look at [Accompanist](https://google.github.io/accompanist/web/), which is "a group of libraries that aim to supplement Jetpack Compose with features that are commonly required by developers but not yet available."

Here's an example:

```
val state = rememberWebViewState("https://example.com")

WebView(
    state
)
```

"By default the WebView will capture back presses/swipes when relevant and navigate the WebView back."

Comment: https://google.github.io/accompanist/web/

Comment: Thanks, I updated the url in my post.

Comment: This library is deprecated, and the API is no longer maintained.